# How to compare 2 Excel sheets and extract the common values?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Table I

| c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ant | Bee | Apple |
| A | B | C |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |

Table II

| A1 | A2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| G | H | Apple |
| H | s | C |
| 8 | asd | 4 |

I would like to know if we can compare these 2 excel workbook (comparison based on the column c3) and extract only the similar values along with the entire row value of that matched value using Pandas

Expected Output:

| c1 | c2 | c3 | A1 | A2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ant | Bee | Apple | G | H |
| A | B | C | H | s |

Comment: Is `c3` unique? if so use it as an index and merge the two tables

Comment: No, the values in c3 are not unique. There are differences in the values. As you can see in the 3rd row of the both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution.
Basically, you should:

- merge dfs with outer join on "c3"
- drop all rows that have any NaN values

  ```
    import pandas as pd

    my_df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': ['Ant', 'A', 4],
                          'c2': ['Bee', 'B', 5],
                          'c3': ['Apple', 'C', 6]
                          })


    my_df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A1': ['G', 'H', 8],
                           'A2': ['H', 's', 'asd'],
                           'c3': ['Apple', 'C', 4]
                          })


    final = my_df.merge(my_df2, on='c3', how='outer').dropna()
  ```

Result:

```
        c1 |  c2 |    c3 | A1  | A2
    -------------------------------
       Ant | Bee | Apple | G   | H
         A |  B  |    C  | H   | s
```

Comment: This is only showing the Indexes/headers. The rows are not included in the result.

Comment: What do you mean ? My result is exactly the same as your Expected Output...